# How to get data from JavaScript code tag with Selenium/PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, phantomjs

I'm looking to get information off a webpage. When I inspect the page source in a browser, I get simple HTML tags, i.e.

```
<h3 class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold">my_title</h3>
```

However, when I run PhantomJS, the information I want is somehow stored in CSS(?) enclosed by an image, i.e. (from driver.getPageSource())

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="display: none" class="datalet-bpr-guid-572130">
    <code style="display: none" id="bpr-guid-572131">
{ /* many lines of code here ... */ {"$deletedFields":["courses","projects","description","recommendations","honors","entityLocale","organizations","region"],"locationName":"my_city,my_state","entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAACJOkiYB8DxCiFxrW3EEdFpeIjMlZ2S84ck,997784449)","companyName":"my_company_name","timePeriod":"urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAACJOkiYB8DxCiFxrW3EEdFpeIjMlZ2S84ck,997784449),timePeriod","company":"urn:li:fs_position:(ACoAACJOkiYB8DxCiFxrW3EEdFpeIjMlZ2S84ck,997784449),company","title":"my_title","companyUrn":"urn:li:fs_miniCompany:5163810","$type":"com.linkedin.voyager.identity.profile.Position"} /* more lines of code */
    </code></img>
```

Is there any way to make the `<code>` become HTML tags like the browser and/or get the data I want from inside the `<code>` with Selenium?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get text inside `<code ...>{ /* many lines of code here ... */ {"$d...</code>`?

Comment: Can you show us your code please? Thanks

Comment: Yes I want to get the text inside <code ...>. My code is

    `driver.get(By.cssSelector("h3[class='Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold']").getAttribute("innerHTML");`

But since the HTML tag dissappears for some reason in PhantomJS that doesn't work

Comment: @jrsstill Can you cross check the css locator if it is a valid one & it's unique? Share the URL if it is public. Thanks